# Windows nuget package-PackageLoader-SpriteRender file Draw error

Tags: c#, monogame, sprite-sheet, win-universal-app

I am trying to an animation using monogame. I tried using TexturePacker Loader nugget package .In the file SpriteRender.cs in the last function:

```
this.spriteBatch.Draw(
            texture: sprite.Texture,
            position: position,
            sourceRectangle: sprite.SourceRectangle,
            color: color,
            rotation: rotation,
            origin: origin,
            scale: new Vector2(scale, scale),
            effect: spriteEffects);
```

am getting error here that says:

```
The best overload for 'Draw' does not have a parameter named 'Position' 
The best overload for 'Draw' does not have a parameter named 'effect'
```

Can someone help me to figure this out

Comment: never mind.. got the answer. effect was changed to effects and it worked. Also rewrote position and that worked too.